# Maven Build on Bamboo

Tags: java, maven, bamboo

I am encountering the following error when creating a plan on Bamboo (Atlassian Build Server). The project builds locally and the configuration is identical to other working projects. If anyone has a clue, it would be grossly appreciated.

```
Beginning to execute external process for build 'Connect Framework - ICPFRAMEWORKBUILD -        
Default Job'
... running command line: 
/data/maven//bin/mvn
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/data/tomcat_ci/temp/ICPFRAMEWORK-BUILD-JOB1
clean
deploy
... in: /data/bamboo_data/xml-data/build-dir/ICPFRAMEWORK-BUILD-JOB1/trunk
... using extra environment variables: 
MAVEN2_HOME=/data/maven/
JAVA_HOME=/data/java6
M2_HOME=/data/maven/
bamboo_productionVersion=2.1

PATH=/data/java6/bin:/data/java6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/   sbin  :/sbin:/home/tomcat/bin
21-Apr-2012 00:59:28    Failing task since return code was -1 while expected 0
```

Comment: Have you tried running the job on another agent? And have you tried a basic Maven build on the same agent in order to test basic functionality?

Answer (score 0):

It seems maven bin directory not in your path variable. if bamboo run in linux environment can you add MAVEN_HOME environment variable and add maven bin directory path to PATH variable.